# Отправка формы методом POST - Bitrix

Tags: html, json, post, битрикс, form

Всем привет! Использую 1c-Bitrix.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при попытке отправить форму методом POST, страница-обработчик, которая указана в action формы открывается как application/json. Проверял настройки главного модуля, htaccess - ничего не нашел. 
Пробовал:

1. Делать форму без подключения ядра битрикса - всё отлично работает.
2. В шаблонах сайта везде явно указано `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
3. У формы прописывал `enctype` - эффекта ноль.
4. Так же проверил кодировку всех файлов. Везде UTF-8

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?  В какую сторону копать?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: У вас форма через ajax уходит на сервер?

Comment: Нет, в том-то и дело. Простая, банальная форма.

Comment: Я бы все-таки посоветовал вам в браузере открыть инспектор кода и проверить какие события на отправке формы висят. Вдруг Bitrix сам вешает такие вещи. Просто application/json это обычно данные в JSON формате отправляемые через ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.

Суть заключалась в том, что предыдущий разработчик, делая AJAX форму(которая присутствует на всех страницах сайта), в своём обработчике проверял на `$_POST`, на общий. Если `$_POST` попадался, то проверял на свои поля, поля не находились и вываливалась ошибка проставляя заголовок в `application/json.` :/

Дорогие разработчики, проверяйте на что проверяете. ;)